# iPhone SDK: How to copy the contents of a NSArray to NSMutable array?

Tags: iphone

I need to copy the contents of an NSArray to NSMutable array. In other words, I want to copy arrayCountryChoices to arraySearchResults. Any ideas????

```
//main data
NSArray *arrayCountryChoices;

//search results buffer 
NSMutableArray *arraySearchResults;


//create data 
arrayCountryChoices = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];   

//copy the original array to searchable array ->> THIS  IS NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
arraySearchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] arrayWithArray:arrayCountryChoices];
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

it's either

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anArray];
```

or

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:anArray];
```

or

```
[anArray mutableCopy];
```

The code in your example doesn't work because you're calling `arrayWithArray` on an instance of `NSMutableArray`, but `arrayWithArray` is a class method.

As a general rule, initalization methods that start with `init` are instance methods, and those that start with the name of the class (`array`, etc.) are class methods. Class methods return autoreleased objects, while instance methods return retained objects.

Comment: //copy the original array to searchable array
 arraySearchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:arrayCountryChoices];

Worked like a champ. Thanks.

Comment: Which of these is more efficient?

Answer (score 4):

You can also create empty mutable array and add objects to it using `-addObjectsFromArray` method

Answer (score 2):

Please note that when using:

```
[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:anArray];
```

or

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:anArray];
```

you'll always get an array even if anArray was nil, but with:

```
[anArray mutableCopy];
```

you'll get nil if anArray is nil. So if you want to be sure that you actually get an array even if it may be empty, use one the former methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `arrayWithArray` is a class method, not an instance method.

You can do `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayCountryChoices]` to do what you need.

You could just call `[arrayCountryChoices mutableCopy]` to return a new mutable array with the contents of `arrayCountryChoices`.