# How to add objects into NSMutableArray without deleting the existing ones?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

Im having trouble with my nsmutablearray in NSUserdefaults, this array every time I relaunch the app erases the objects that already are there and put the new ones, so I need help to prevent these to happen, Thanks and this is my code;

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
    [userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
    //[userDefaults synchronize];
    NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
    NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count);
```

And Im reading it in a tableview this way:

```
cell.taskTitle.text = (self.TasksArray)[indexPath.row];
```

Thanks!

Comment: Initialize the array with the current values from `NSUserDefaults`, then add the new value, then save the updated list back to `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a line of code there:

```
self.tasks = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[userDefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"];
```

As far as I can tell, you're not initially setting your "`.tasks`" property, so adding that bit may fix the problem.

Comment: self.tasks might be nil if "`[userDefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"]`" is nil.  So we're protecting against that.

Comment: Okay @mustafabesnili you win... I see Konrad's answer [in this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12728920/981049).  I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get it from user defaults first as rmaddy suggests. Your `nil` check will then create a new array if its never been created/saved before.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

self.tasks = [[userDefaults objectForKey:@"tasks"] mutableCopy];

if (!self.tasks) self.tasks = [NSMutableArray new];

[self.tasks addObject:textField.text];
[userDefaults setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
//[userDefaults synchronize];
NSLog(@"tasks:%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]);
NSLog(@"number of tasks:%d", self.tasks.count);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you never call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];`
Once you finish with changes of your object you should call it since it saves your changes to disk.

Comment: You are correct but you still do not know when is that "periodically" moment. Calling synchronized can sometimes save your hair in the end :)